# 'This' function is not equivalent (isomorphic) to the function restored from a checkpoint in CNTK

Tags: python, restore, cntk

I got the following exception in calling `trainer.restore_from_checkpoint` in CNTK.

> 'This' function is not equivalent (isomorphic) to the function restored from a checkpoint.

My restoring code comes in the below. These are the same as the structure of the creating the trainer and saving the `trainer.dnn` by `trainer.save_checkpoint("trainer.dnn")` as mentioned [in this document](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Load-pre-trained-checkpointed-model-and-continue-retraining).

```
def evaluate(reader, model):
    criterion = create_criterion_function(model)
    criterion.replace_placeholders({criterion.placeholders[0]: Input(input_dim),
                                    criterion.placeholders[1]: Input(label_dim)})

    # training config
    epoch_size = 34  
    minibatch_size = 17

    # LR schedule over epochs 
    lr_per_sample = [0.003]*4+[0.0015]*24+[0.0003]
    lr_per_minibatch = [x * minibatch_size for x in lr_per_sample]
    lr_schedule = learning_rate_schedule(lr_per_minibatch, UnitType.minibatch, epoch_size)

    # Momentum
    momentum_as_time_constant = momentum_as_time_constant_schedule(70)

    learner = adam_sgd(criterion.parameters,
                       lr=lr_schedule, momentum=momentum_as_time_constant,
                       low_memory=True,
                       gradient_clipping_threshold_per_sample=15, gradient_clipping_with_truncation=True)

    trainer = Trainer(model, criterion.outputs[0], criterion.outputs[1], learner)
    trainer.restore_from_checkpoint("trainer.dnn")

def do_test():
    reader = create_reader('Test.txt', is_training=False)
    model = create_model()
    evaluate(reader, model)

do_test()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to checkpoints.

1. Model check-pointing: Checkpoint the model only, then when you restore the model, create a new trainer.
2. Trainer check-pointing: Checkpoint the trainer which will save the model, and the criterion functions. Restore the trainer from the checkpoint.

This error could come because you have a criterion function being passed to the trainer and then restoring from a previous checkpoint that has a different function.

Some relevant code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/746d2112c64281c21f7a45f9f9632fd98967d086/bindings/python/cntk/tests/trainer_test.py)

Comment: Using from a global criterion function and model, but get the same error. Also, in the mentioned code in my question, I created the same criterion function as the function which was stored. Could you recommend any sample code which works fine somehow, store the trainer, and after some computation, in an arbitrary point restore that trainer?

Comment: There is some code that users restore_from_checkpoint  here. https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/3ab246855bff036eefe61d30658be5112567f492/bindings/python/cntk/tests/distributed_test.py

Comment: this example is very bad, as it is not applicable! after a line of saving checkpoint, restored the checkpoint which this is not the applicable case!!! I have been do that before and it works, but not applicable! In most of the case I want to restore the checkpoint when I need it, not exactly after saving the checkpoint!!!

Comment: Thanks OmG. We are tracking this in the github issues (https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/1353). Thanks for working with us on it.